# Fusioncharts couple angulargouge to a database and Double arrow message showing up

Tags: php, jquery, database, fusioncharts

I'm trying to find a way to get information out of a database and use this information in a graph. Im using a libery (FusionCharts), this has some examples but not with data out of a database. So far i came up this this but im getting an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

The example im using is this one [Example angulargauge](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/6nVm2/)

```
 if ($result) {

$arrData6 = array(
  "chart" => array
  (
            "caption" => "Sended mail",
            "lowerlimit" => "0",
            "upperlimit" => "100",
            "lowerlimitdisplay" =>"0%",
            "upperlimitdisplay" => "100%",
            "palette" => "1",
            "numbersuffix" => "%",
            "tickvaluedistance" => "10",
            "showvalue" => "0",
            "gaugeinnerradius" => "0",
            "bgcolor" => "FFFFFF",
            "pivotfillcolor" => "333333",
            "pivotradius" => "8",
            "pivotfillmix" => "333333, 333333",
            "pivotfilltype" => "radial",
            "pivotfillratio"=> "0,100",
            "showtickvalues"=> "1",
            "showborder" => "0",
        ),

    "colorRange" => array (
    "color" => array
        (
            "minValue" => "0",
            "maxValue" => "50",
            "code" => "#e44a00"
        ),
        (
            "minValue" => "50",
            "maxValue" => "75",
            "code" => "#f8bd19"
        ),
        (
            "minValue" => "75",
            "maxValue" => "100",
            "code" => "#6baa01"
        )
),
"dials" => array (
    "dial" => array (
        "value" => "$precentage"
    )
)
  );

  $arrData6["data"] = array();

  $jsonEncodedData6 = json_encode($arrData6);

  $angularChart = new FusionCharts("AngularGauge", "chart4" , "100%", "200", "chart-5", "json", $jsonEncodedData6);
    // Render the chart
    $angularChart->render();
}
```

I can up with this by using the information on the page but since this one got more informatiesets (chart,dials and colors) I haven't been able to figure out how to do it yet.[Database how to explaination i used](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/php/creating-charts-with-data-from-a-database.html)

The $percentage is the result of the total - the not sended mail